# Meteor.js update only one parameter instead of whole collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to mark message as readed using code below :

```
Template.FullMessage.onRendered(function () {
            var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
            Messages.update(id, {$set: {readed: true} });
});
```

Collection is :

```
"_id": "YMxYn9NodPeZqFP83",
  "whatAbout": "adsfadsfasdf",
  "message": "sdfadsfadfadsfasdfasdf",
  "recipientId": "9ewiF8JTNp77Pmijw",
  "author": "9ewiF8JTNp77Pmijw",
  "createdAt": "2016-05-09T08:37:52.282Z",
  "owner": "seofilms",
  "readed": false
}
```

I expected that column "readed":"false" will be replaced with "readed":true,

but instead of it, everything in here is changing, including owner. So for instance if I will open message with user test, I will change also the owner of this message.

Why does it happens ?

Is it possible to prevent sending whole object and change it only with ID?

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: It should work out of the box. By passing id, the way you do it should only update the specific property of the specific object. Is there any other code writing to the collection? Try run in in console.

Comment: In console it works well.No, there is only this code, I'm also sure that there are no any different code who change it, because if I will remove this  line it's don't do anything at all. I will try create new simple project without any different code and will see wether it's working the same way or not.

Comment: @Lezhnev Victor : Before calling the `Messages.update(...)` function, can you display all the item in the `Messages` collection ? Maybe the collection is not properly initialized ?

Comment: @JeanMel Yes, I'm displaing them in Template MyMessages and it's working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Messages.update({_id: id}, {$set: {readed: true} });
```

It should also work with only `id`, as you're already doing. Is there any other code that's writing to the same collection? Try to run it in console and check if it's still updating all the properties.

Comment: Unfortunately the same result.

Comment: I've updated my answer. My guess is that there's something else going on here.

Comment: You was right, problem is somewhere else I'm using SimpleSchema and I had autoValue() there, so I replaced autoValue() to defaultValue() and everything works well. Thank you. @smoksnes